# jQuery remove an element if radio button is not checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code that append elements to the document if the corresponding radio button is checked. This works fine, however I need a way to remove the elements if the radio button is NOT checked.

Here is what I have so far?

```
// for each radio button
$('input[type=radio]').each(function(){ 

    // if it is checked
    if($(this).is(":checked")) 
        {
        var cur = $(this).val();
        // append an input text element only if it does not already exist
      if(!$('#characterList input:text').is(function(i,e){ return e.value==cur && e.name=='data['+cur+']'; }))
      {
        $('#characterList').append('<input type="text" name="data[' + $(this).val() + ']" value="' + $(this).val() + '" />');
      }
    }
   else
   {
    // otherwise remove element if radio button not checked
    $('#characterList').remove('<input type="text" name="data[' + $(this).val() + ']" value="' + $(this).val() + '" />');   
   }

   });
 });
```

The `.remove(...)` does nothing at all. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809448/adding-and-removing-elements-dynamically-based-on-checkbox-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`remove()` doesn't work like that. You have to provide a selector to select the element you wish to remove. This can be done like so:

```
$('#characterList').remove('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');
```

Or, alternatively:

```
$('#characterList').find('input[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').remove();
```

Furthermore, instead of using `$(this).is(":checked")` and `$(this).val()`, you can simply use:

```
if ( this.checked )
```

And:

```
var cur = this.value;
```